# Are OEM USB drivers needed for developing Android apps on Windows 10?

Tags: usb, usb-debugging, usb-drivers

On Linux, to develop an Android app there are no USB drivers needed. Regardless of whether android device comes from most popular or totally unknown hardware make, it just works.

On Windows in turn, one has to install OEM USB drivers to run app on particular device which can be painful if the device is not one of the most popular hardware brand that provides its own USB drivers.

Just reading an [official Android documentation on OEM drivers](http://developer.android.com/tools/extras/oem-usb.html) and can't see any instructions on how to install USB drivers for Windows 10.

So, are OEM USB drivers needed for developing apps on Windows 10?
Or maybe, wishful thinking, Windows 10 does take similar approach as Linux does?

Answer (score 2):

No, the ADB drivers included with the Android SDK are universal.

On Windows 7, I was able to use the Google driver to interface with

1) Three different models of the Kindle Fire
2) Nexus 5,7
3) ZTE Speed
4) LG Optimus F3
5) HP Touchpad
6) Galaxy S4
7) Asus Memo Pad 8
8) Galaxy S3
9) Generic unbranded tablet

Comment: Surely Google USB driver may work with a number of devices but it's definitely not universal. I have a bunch of Android devices right on my desk that do not work with Google USB driver.

Comment: Just because Windows says, "We couldn't find driver software for your device" even though you pointed it to the correct driver; doesn't mean it isn't the right driver. I had a heck of a time forcing Windows to install the driver, but after I did it worked fine.

Comment: Interesting conversation.  I guess I've just had good luck.  @matcheek 's response makes me wonder if I'm just getting lucky when I test with major vendors like Samsung devices.

Comment: I just wonder how the explanation of "on Windows 7" addresses the OPs question of "Windows 10"? I see no indicator here claiming it was kept that way (which I'd assume) or not (which still is possible). Especially with the drivers of the AndroidSDK *not* being "universal" (we had quite a few complaints on exactly that here in the past), could you please [edit] your answer and detail on that? Also note OP says there are no instructions on how to install those USB drivers on Windows 10 – another detail possibly missing here.

Comment: @Izzy Windows kicks and screams that the Google driver isn't compatible, but if you modify the `.inf` file you can get it to work.

Comment: So maybe you could [edit] your answer again and outline that (what has to be modified and in what way)?